# How to implement a subscription in a mobile application (iOS / Android)?

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase

I want to develop an application (iOS / Android) in which the user will have access to certain content only by paying a monthly subscription.
I have never come across this and now I don’t even quite understand where it is better to begin to approach this issue and what kind of implementation it will have.

Now I imagine this as follows:
The application will be inAppPurchase information about which will be sent to the server with a RESTful API on which I will store information about users and their subscriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IAPs are not particularly easy to implement. I would suggest you start by understanding different concepts around IAPs and how the client and the server play together, a good starting point is [RevenueCat - iOS Subscriptions are Hard](https://medium.com/revenuecat-blog/ios-subscriptions-are-hard-d9b29c74e96f)
. The concepts are similar in Google Billing, and I would read their [Overview](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview) documentation.